# Editable HTML, CSS and Javascript within Powerpoint Presentation?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, plunker

I was wondering if it was possible to have an editable HTML demo interface (like Plunkr) inside powerpoint for doing educational presentations on HTML, JavaScript, etc.

Has anyone done this? Is it possible to embed an iFrame with a link to plunkr or local node server within powerpoint?

Cheers,
DS

Answer (score 7):

You can do it now with Powerpoint Online and the 'Web Viewer' Addin

1) Open your presentation on https://onedrive.live.com

2) Add an addin called 'Web Viewer' from MS

[image]

3) Insert it to the presentation and put in your content's url

[image]

4) End result

[image]

Comment: Great! Cool answer

Answer (score 5):

You can embed a browser control into a PPT slide (use Shyam's free Live Web add-in if you don't want to mess with doing it in code:  http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm).

Comment: Live Web does not support Canvas and potentially other features of HTML5/CSS3.

Comment: More accurately, Live Web inserts a MS web browser control into your PPT. The browser control hosts an instance of MSIE.  It'd be MSIE that doesn't support these add'l features. Perhaps one of the browsers that does support the needed features also offers an insertable browser control usable in PPT.

Comment: According to Live Web's F.A.Q.s, the default version of IE used by the browser control is IE7, though there are ways of using a more recent version. Then again, after setting the default to IE10, I was still unable to even get some simple JavaScript to run. I'm not sure JavaScript is still supported.

Comment: JavaScript is supported but the IE security settings may have disabled it.

Answer (score 4):

I use [slides.com](http://slides.com/) for educational presentations (well, educating to myself at the very least). To be more specific, I did a few small JavasScript talks at our local JavaScript meetup here - nothing fancy, but works.

I think you should be able to add some remote code in there.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: no. You can't embed iframes in powerpoints. Perhaps there are Chrome/FF extensions that allow you to embed things into Google Docs Presentations (which are HTML5/SVG based), but other than that, this is not possible. I have no idea if any such extension exists, but I am quite convinced it should be possible to make.