# Easy way to export Vega interactive Visualization into PowerPoint (and keep interactivity)

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Looking to export Vega (or Vega-Lite) into PowerPoint as an interactive visualization.  Are there any known libraries/techniques to do this easily? If not with Vega, are there other interactive visualization libraries you would recommend with this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive Vega/Vega-Lite charts are rendered via HTML and Javascript, so your question is equivalent to asking whether arbitrary HTML/JS documents can be displayed in Powerpoint. The answer appears to be yes, if you're using Powerpoint Online with the WebViewer addon; see [Editable HTML, CSS and Javascript within Powerpoint Presentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257042/editable-html-css-and-javascript-within-powerpoint-presentation)

You can create an HTML view of your chart using [Vega-Embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#basic-example), and then use this in the online powerpoint.